# ListView in integration test (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, listview, testing, driver, integration

I haven't found a complex examples for testing ListViews. Example.

I have a ListView, which has three objects `Person`.

```
Person{
   String name;
   String surname;
}
```

In UI, `Person` is wrapped in `Column`, giving them two `Text` Widgets for `name` and `surname`.

I click on FAB. Clicking on FAB adds new `Person` with `name` `Tom` and surname `Thomson` to the `ListView`. Now there are 4 objects of `Person`. And I know data of the last one.

How can I validate, that item was successfully added? Is there a way to check `length/count` of `ListView`?
Is there a way to validate last added item params?

Appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

`widgetList` provides a matching widget in the tree, just need to mention key of `Listview` which required to test.

```
final count = tester
          .widgetList<ListView>(find.byKey(ValueKey("ListViewKey")))
          .length;
```

Comment: Thank you, Jitesh. I'm not able to verify this answer as I'm not working on that project anymore. However, it does seems like a good fit for it. Cheers

Comment: I get the number of ListView instead of its children. It always returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

I add my ListTile titles with a unique key *(ex. 'tile_surname_#')*. Assuming your ListView is built with an array of Person objects called persons, you can try something like:

```
    final String valueKey = 'tile_$newPerson.surname_${persons.length}';
    final newPersonFinder = find.byValueKey(valueKey);
    expect(
       await driver.getText(newPersonFinder), valueKey
    );
```

Comment: Yes, I use similar pattern. But that seems extremely manual and code becomes hard to handle with keys being everywhere.
 What about delete case?
There are 4 objects now, `person` `Tom` gets deleted.

How to validate, that `Person` `Tom` doesn't exist in List anymore? Because `getText` in this case will never execute because object doesn't exist.

Comment: try the waitForAbsent method

Comment: Im not sure that's the right usecase for using it, because `waitForAbsent` is used for cases when you expect widget to disappear. In this particular case, widget simply is not located. I'd expect there to be some kind of `expect` statement.

Comment: true, but if you "await driver.waitForAbsent(deletedPerson)" and the person was not removed from the ListView, then the test will fail with a timeout exception.

Comment: Correct, what I was trying to do is to wrap it to try catch, however it doesn't seem to work. First `DriverError` appears, then `TimeoutException` which is goes though whole try catch clause and still fails the test.